# How to get the text if it is outside the tag in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<i class="icon solr-icon icon-ic-city"></i>"Solapur"
```

So I want to get the text with the help of i tag, but the problem is
text "Pune" is out side the i tag. I can make use of li tag but I do not to do that. Can anyone tell me how to get text if the text is
outside the tag?

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe that there is a specific option to do this is selenium and you would have to select the enclosing element and then retrieve the `innerHTML` to get the source including the text you are interesed and then parse the source by most likely just removing the  tag.

`element.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Comment: I can get text with the help of getText method from 'li' tag, I want to know how to get text with the help of 'i' tag.
Text is out the i tag, I want to get the text that is out side the i tag. for now just assume that there is no li tag. How would you get text if there was no list tag in my example?

Comment: Did you try what i proposed? Did it work?